# check login error ReferenceError: currentuser is not defined at app.js:34

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a Reactjs application for the first time.
I create two global variables but one is working and the other one is not working.
'loggedInStatus' updates and returns what is expected and 'currentuser' shows in chrome developer tools as "check login error ReferenceError: currentuser is not defined at app.js:34"

I have four components app.js Home.sj auth/login.js and Dashboard.js
I created two variables as follow in app.js to be able to call them from the other components.

```
this.state = {
  loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN",
  currentuser: {}
}
```

I am setting both at the same time every where in the application
Please help me understand why currentuser is not working.
Here is my repository if it is necessary:

https://github.com/caroe2014/printshop-frontend-reactjs.git

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to pass the user a parameter to dashboard

```
        <Route 
        exact 
        path={"/dashboard"} 
        render={props => (
          <Dashboard 
            { ...props}  
            checkLoginStatus={this.checkLoginStatus}   
            loggedInStatus={this.state.loggedInStatus}
            currentuser={this.state.currentuser} 
          />
        )}
```